# Gatling - change SSL cert used in feeder per request?

Tags: scala, ssl, https, gatling

Is it possible in Gatling to use feeder with different certificate for every request?

Consider the test:

- for a number of users, each has a personal, unique certificate used for HTTPS connection,
- for every user, send a request, using that user's certificate.

Example implementation:

```
val feeder = Array(
  Map("data" -> data(user1_data),
    "gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.file" -> "/tmp/test-data/rb.jks",
    "gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.password" -> "password",
    "gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file" -> "/tmp/test-data/user1.jks",
    "gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.password" -> "password"),

  Map("data" -> data(user2_data),
    "gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.file" -> "/tmp/test-data/rb.jks",
    "gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.password" -> "password",
    "gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file" -> "/tmp/test-data/user2.jks",
    "gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.password" -> "password")
)
...
val scn = scenario.exec(reportableTest(
  repeat(feeder.length) {
    feed(feeder)
    .exec(http("test user personal data")
    .post(user_url)
    .headers(user_headers)
    .body(StringBody("${data}")).asJSON
    .check(
      status.is(201),
      header("Content-type").is("application/json"),
    )
}))
```

I did call: .disableClientSharing in scenario setup.

The weird behaviour is, it seems that only the first

```
"gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file" -> "/tmp/test-data/user1.jks",
```

is processed. The next are not (even if I create another reportableTest). I've simply changed the order to see that in fact in both request the first "userX.jks" is being used.

Is this the normal behaviour? 
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on Gatling's Google Group: SSL config can be set per virtual user, not per request.

Comment: Of course. After your answer a colleague pointed the "repeat" part - causing all feeder requests to be consumed by a single user. It worked without that (with 2 users for 2 requests). Thanks for help and quick reply